# BulkLoader behaviour changing when loading from internet

Tags: actionscript-3, bulkloader

I'm using BulkLoader to load in images, SWFs, XML, etc into a game.

When working local, the `content` property on the `LoadingItem` is always good depending on the type of asset: `Bitmap` if it's an image, `MovieClip` if it's a SWF etc.

When I test the same swf, but under localhost, or online, the `content` property is always a `Loader` object.

Is this normal? Am I missing out a parameter or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for those that have the same problem - ImageLoader, line 57:

```
override public function onCompleteHandler(evt : Event) : void {
    try{
        // of no crossdomain has allowed this operation, this might
        // raise a security error
        _content = loader.content;
        super.onCompleteHandler(evt);
    }catch(e : SecurityError){
        // we can still use the Loader object (no dice for accessing it as data
        // though. Oh boy:
        _content = loader;
        super.onCompleteHandler(evt);
        // I am really unsure whether I should throw this event
        // it would be nice, but simply delegating the error handling to user's code 
        // seems cleaner (and it also mimics the Standar API behaviour on this respect)
        //onSecurityErrorHandler(e);
    }

};
```

Basically what was happening was that a `SecurityError` was occurring (though silently), which would set the `content` property to the `Loader` and not the `Loader.content`.

It was fixed with adding a `Security.loadPolicyFile()` before loading.